# Exercise about a line perpendicular to a plane

Tags: geometry

This exercise says that $K$ is midpoint of $DG$ and $KP$ is perpendicular to $AK$. It asks then, that if there exists a perpendicular segment to a plane in this picture.

Obviously, $KP$ doesn't need to be perpendicular to the plane $E$, because by the definition, it must be perpendicular to all the lines in the plane. There's another theorem that extracts from this definition, that it must be, in fact, perpendicular to two lines on the plane.

So I'm thinking that $DG$ should be perpendicular to the plane $AKP$, since $DG$ is perpendicular to $AK$. But how do I prove that $DG$ is perpendicular to $KP$?

Is my intuition correct?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking whether or not $KP$ is _always_ perpendicular to the plane $E$ or are you asking _when_ is it perpendicular to the plane $E$?  From the given, $KP$ is not necessarily perpendicular to the plane $E$.  That right angle can rotate along the line segment $AK$.  Do you agree that $KD$ is perpendicular to $AK$?  If so, then $KP$ could be along $KD$ and thus _part_ of the plane E.

Comment: Yes, $AK\perp DGP$ I think is meant to be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

just take the cross product of AK and D G and place it on K. Taking cross product is a geometric and allowable construction in Euclidean Geometry.